Can't set Xrandr refresh above 60fps, despite windows doing 165
I have an HP Victus Laptop with an Nvidia 3090. I've been trying to set the display mode of my monitor to 3440x1440 165 fps:
xrandr --output DP-1-0 --mode 3440x1440 --rate 165

This doesn't throw any errors, but it doesn't work. It keeps resetting itself to 60fps. This happens with or without freesync on.

figured it out, the issue was grobi being installed and starting despite being dactivated
